# MockBean of MongoDB repository - only save produces described result, other mock methods return null

Tags: spring, mongodb, unit-testing, mockito

I am testing a service that has a MongoDB ReactiveMongoRepository repo dependency.
I am using @MockBean to inject mock repository.
Only 1 of 4 defined when().thenReturn() work , the rest produce null when running the Unit Test.
Here is the code:

```
    @Autowired
private BlogpostServicePersist testee;

@MockBean
private BlogpostRepository repo;
private Class<BlogpostMongoDoc> entityClass = BlogpostMongoDoc.class;
private String testId1 = "save 01 ID";
private BlogpostMongoDoc postMongoDOc = (BlogpostMongoDoc) initialize(
        BlogpostMongoDoc.newInstance(testId1, "save 01 title", "save 01 text", "save 01 author"));;
private BlogpostDTO postDTO = (BlogpostDTO) initialize(
        BlogpostDTO.newInstance(testId1, "save 01 title", "save 01 text", "save 01 author"));

@BeforeAll
void setup() {
    when(repo.save(any(entityClass))).thenReturn(just(postMongoDOc));
    when(repo.deleteById(anyString())).thenReturn(Mono.empty().then());
    when(repo.findById(eq(testId1))).thenReturn(just(postMongoDOc));
    when(repo.findAll()).thenReturn(Flux.just(postMongoDOc, postMongoDOc));
}

@Test
void testSave() {
    create(testee.save(postDTO)).expectNextMatches(this::matchPost).expectComplete().verify();
}

@Test
void testGetStream() {
    create(testee.getAll()).expectNextMatches(this::matchPost).expectNextMatches(this::matchPost).expectComplete()
            .verify();
}

@Test
void testDelete() {
    create(testee.delete(testId1)).expectComplete().verify();
}

@Test
void testGetByID() {
    create(testee.getByID(testId1)).expectNextMatches(this::matchPost).expectComplete().verify();
}
```

testSave works fine. Here is the service code:

```
    @Override
public Mono<BlogpostDTO> save(BlogpostDTO newPost) {
    return repo.save(toEntity(newPost)).map(this::toDTO);
}
```

On the rest there is NullPointer exception in the service when the repo returns a value,
for example:

```
    @Override
public Mono<BlogpostDTO> getByID(String id) {
    return repo.findById(id).map(this::toDTO);
}
```

return repo.findById(id) returns null.

I have equals defined on the entity class BlogpostMongoDoc that I am using and it s based on String ID field.

What is the difference between when(save) definition and the rest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The same *when* definitions work when moved from *beforeAll* to test methods:

```
    @Test
void testGetStream() {
    when(repo.findAll()).thenReturn(Flux.just(postMongoDOc, postMongoDOc));
    create(testee.getAll()).expectNextMatches(this::matchPost).expectNextMatches(this::matchPost).expectComplete()
            .verify();
    verify(repo).findAll();
}
```